# How to connect Expo with arduino

Tags: react-native, arduino, expo

I want to connect my apps with Arduino which can control the switch through the apps.

However, I found out that expo does not support Bluetooth and I'm trying to use another way by communicating through the serial port which also unsuccessful also because Expo does not support it.

Are there any other ways to connect Expo projects with Arduino?

Comment: Is it essential for you to use expo? beacuse if it isn't I would suggest just ejecting and using a plain react native package that supports it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible for 2 reasons:

- Arduino doesn't have BT
- Expo is a multi platform mobile SDK. But since iOS has a bad and incomplete BT implementation, Expo will probably not implement it.

You can add a BT module to your Arduino like HC-05 or HM-10. (use HM-10 if you want to connect it with iOS, since iOS is not able to transmit data over the standard SPP - Serial Protocol Profile).

There are some apps on the store to connect a HM-10 devices and switch on/off something:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.argonremote.bluetoothcontroller

Or you can use an ESP32 instead of an Arduino. So you will be able to connect it over WiFi or BT.